# Edit recurring calendar item instance from workflow

Tags: workflow, recurring-events

I've created a workflow that edit the title of a calendar item. When applying the workflow on a recurring item all items are changed ... How to make only the current calendar item instance changing?

Comment: Does the rename take place on item creation or is it manually fired?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the title for an individual instance. This is because the SharePoint run time is expanding the recurrence information on the first instance to create in memory calendar items when a view is loaded.

SharePoint does not support customisation of individual instances of recurring items